# i want to learn 3D Animation who can help me

Tags: animation

I want to learn 3D Animation. do anybody know good resources to learn Animation in Blender 
I am beginner in this also resources should be free cause I don't have money

Comment: Try searching "blender beginner tutorial" on youtube, and go from there. I recommend the donut series by Blender Guru, for example.

Comment: Try -CGCookie -Turtle animation course on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9whe0Ham7GI .It's covers everything- modelling,sculpting,shape keys, rigging , animation etc

Comment: Go to page 4 for the playlists of tutorials suitable for absolute beginners. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13UpIjJEE7Oa7x5BiMsjXGW5CGOTDF03-SocRYi4Babs

Comment: also, rigging a human character and creating a walk cycle is a good exercice

Comment: You might want to check some **lazy tutorial** from [IanHubert](https://www.youtube.com/user/mrdodobird). Those clip provide a very wide vision of animation creation process in the most genius method.